# Call stack management

Tags: haskell, compilation, callstack

This isn't really a Haskell question at all, but I imagine there are a lot of people following the Haskell tag who will know the answer to this...

I'm currently trying to wrap my brain around how you can hold a function's inputs *and* outputs *and* local variables *and* temporary values all on the same stack, yet end up with the correct stack layout on exit.

Usually a *stack* provides Push and Pull operations, which modify the top-most stack item only. Sometimes you're also allowed random read access to items further down the stack. (That explains how you can keep variables there and random-access them.) But usually the only way to change the size of the stack is to Pull items off it. That's not much good if you want to keep the item on top of the stack and delete stuff below it.

How do real compilers do this stuff?

Comment: Under what circumstances would something need to be deleted from the call stack that isn't on the top?

Comment: @sepp2k Usually you push arguments onto the stack, call the function, and when it comes back the result is the only thing on the stack. Well if you've got a bunch of arguments and then a bunch of locals and then finally you've built the result on the very top of the stack, you need to somehow chuck all the stuff below it before you return...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call stack *frame* can just have the space reserved for the return value *before* the space where the arguments go, and then the locals. That's why knowing the type helps decide the size of that reserved space. Or, in dynamic languages like Lisp, the pointer to the boxed value would go there. It's just a part of a particular function call protocol.

BTW the run-time stack in languages with closures is usually a tree (see "the Funarg problem").

Comment: So you reserve space for the return value before you push everything else on, and on return you just drop everything but the result?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I think this would work, yes. The order of placement on stack doesn't have to correspond to the temporal order of initiation of entities.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to Haskell directly, but in general it's the job of the application binary interface (or ABI) to specify how data is passed to and from functions (known as the calling convention). Depending on the calling convention and the size of the data, some or all of the things you mention may be stored in registers (or even a global) instead of the stack. Furthermore, the return address to the calling function and possibly some processor state will also be stored on the stack.

Take, for example, the [OS X IA-32 Function Calling Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/130-IA-32_Function_Calling_Conventions/IA32.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002492-SW4). The stack layout:

[image: OS X IA-32 stack convention]

In this calling convention, return values are usually stored in a register